# Reading binary file C++

Tags: c++, fread

Please, help me. I can't read binary file. The file's length is 198944, but my code reads 374.  I tried to use fread, ifstream, WinAPI ReadFile.
This is the function that reads file:

```
std::string ReadThisFile(std::string aPath) {
   FILE *inputstream = fopen(aPath.c_str(),"rb");
   long size;
   size_t result; 
   fseek(inputstream,0,SEEK_END); 
   size = ftell(inputstream); 
   rewind(inputstream); 
   char *buff = new char [size];
   result = fread (buff,1,size,inputstream); 
   std::string ret=buff; 
   fclose(inputstream); 
   delete[]buff; 
   return ret; 
}
```

[File sample](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/41777790/file.dat)

Any help is needed, thank you!

Comment: Are you using `strlen` to get the final size? You can't do store binary content in a string.

Comment: Is the file supposed to be an ASCII text file you want to load into a single `std::string`? If not, use a different container. (like a `std::vector<unsigned char>` or something similar).

Comment: Btw, `fseek(binary_stream, offset, SEEK_END)` is not guaranteed to work (according to the C standard from 1999).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you're aware of that the `std::string` that you return contains binary data, replace

```
std::string ret=buff;
```

with

```
std::string ret(buff, size);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't put binary data in a string. Remember that a string is terminated by the special character `'\0'` which is the same as the value zero. If the binary data contains a zero, that is the same as the end of the string.

You should probably use a `std::vector<int8_t>` to store binary data.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, that was my problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
std::string ret = buff;
```

According to [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/string/), it:

> "Copies the **null-terminated** character sequence (C-string) pointed by s."

So it stops as soon as a `0x00` character is reached.

If you were to return `buff` (which is a dangerous practice) or have your function take a char array as an input parameter and merely store it there, it should work. And you may want to return a length indicator, since otherwise C++ will not know how large the array is.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, that was my problem.